# Can't run IOS application in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-ios

Here is the image of error code i already try with pod update and repo pod update and clean derived data

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this lines to your Podfile

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ARCHS'] = 'armv7 armv7s'
    end
  end
end
```

Flutter

- ios

  - Podfile

Answer (score 0):

First Delete ios Folder in your project

```dart
flutter create .
```

in terminal

then change ios version in your podfile to 10

then try to run it again and please backup ios folder if you have created or added files in ios